# How to modify the Html Resulting from a dropdownlistfor?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I'm working on modifying the CSS of a Select Tag. The Select tag is generated using @Html.DropDownListFor Helper. To change the CSS of the arrow of the select element i need to have a label before or a div incapsulating the select to play with the :before :after. I don't want my developpers to write this on every dropdown.

How can i modify the html response of the helper before sending it the view to add a label for example.

Thanks

Comment: What you're looking to build is called a "custom HTML helper". 
 There are plenty of examples you can find on Google to get you started.  For example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs

Comment: @David Actually i already know about custom ones, i want to override the main function to keep it's normal validations, intercept the result, and do my modification on it to not break the main behavior.

Comment: @tahtoh Provide your `@Html.DropDownListFor` code in the question.

Comment: Its the System.Web.Mvc code built in @TanvirArjel